# If $|x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}| \le c|x_{n+1} - x_n|$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $0 \le c < 1$, then $(x_n)$ has a bounded variation.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> A sequence $(x_n)$ is said to have a bounded variation in case the sequence $(v_n)$ given by $v_n=\sum_{i=1}^n |x_{i+1} - x_i|$ is bounded.

The task itself is to prove the following:

- If $|x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}| \le c|x_{n+1} - x_n|$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $0 \le c < 1$, then $(x_n)$ has a bounded variation.

**My attempt:**

First, let the sequence $(y_n)$ be given by $y_n = |x_{n+1} - x_n|$. Then, I broke it down in two cases: $0<c<1$ (I) and $c=0$ (II).

- For (I), we have that $\lim \frac{|y_{n+1}|}{|y_n|}<1$.Hence, by the ratio test, the series $\sum y_n = \sum |x_{n+1}-x_n|$ is convergent, and for the sequence of its partial sums, which is $(v_n)$, we have that it is bounded. We conclude $(x_n)$ has a bounded variation.
- For (II), I'm not sure. Perhaps taking the limit of the absolute value $|x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}| \le 0$ would imply that the series $\sum y_n$ converges to $0$?

Is it Ok to break this problem down in the two former cases like I did?

Comment: If $|x|\le 0$, then $x=0$. In your case, that'd mean all $y_n=0$.

Comment: So, then that'd imply that $y_n$ is a constant sequence and obviously converges to $0$. So can I say that $(x_n)$ has a bounded variation from that too?

Comment: Yeah, then $x_n$ is constant, too, so the sequence $v_n$ in the definition is all zeros.

Comment: @Al.G. thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

I would start with noticing that:

\begin{align*}
|x_{n + 1} - x_{n}| \leq c|x_{n} - x_{n-1}| \leq c^{2}|x_{n - 1} - x_{n - 2}|\leq \ldots \leq c^{n}|x_{1} - x_{0}|
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah. We could sum both sides $\sum_{k=1}^n |x_{k+1} - x_k| \le \sum_{k=1}^n c^k|x_1 - x_0|$.     And, since the geometric series converges, we conclude what we wanted. But I'd like to know if what I did is Ok too.

Comment: If $c = 0$, then each term $y_{n} = 0$. Hence the $v_{n}$ converges to $0$, whence one concludes it is bounded. If $0 < c < 1$, you can apply the ratio test as you did to conclude $v_{n}$ converges. That is because:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|y_{n + 1}|}{|y_{n}|} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} c = c < 1$$

Comment: Hmm, alright. Thanks for the help!!!